# Python No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json

I am having an issue with JSON, I can't seem to figure out why this is not working. This is supposed to output JSON.

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import struct
import json

def unpack_varint(s):
    d = 0
    i = 0
    while True:
        b = ord(s.recv(1))
        d |= (b & 0x7F) << 7*i
        i += 1
        if not b & 0x80:
            return d

def pack_data(d):
    return struct.pack('>b', len(d)) + d

def pack_port(i):
    return struct.pack('>H', i)

def get_info(host, port=25565):

    # Connect
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))

    # Send handshake + status request
    s.send(pack_data("\x00\x00" + pack_data(host.encode('utf8')) + pack_port(port) + "\x01"))
    s.send(pack_data("\x00"))

    # Read response
    unpack_varint(s)     # Packet length
    unpack_varint(s)     # Packet ID
    l = unpack_varint(s) # String length

    d = ""
    while len(d) < l:
        d += s.recv(1024)

    # Close our socket
    s.close()

    # Load json and return
    return json.loads(d.decode('utf8'))
get_info('162.213.43.124');
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 46, in 
    get_info('162.213.43.124');
  File "main.py", line 45, in get_info
    return json.loads(d.decode('utf8'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

If anyone could come to the rescue that would be awesome!

Comment: > your json is invalid

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems that you have invalid JSON. In that case, that's totally dependent on the data the server sends you which you have not shown. I would suggest running the response through a [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: I'm new to python, how would I get the output that the server is sending so I could put it into JSON Validator?

Comment: @Mario - `print d.decode('utf-8')` or if using python 3.x `print(d.decode('utf-8'))`