# Python Json Error: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json

I'm getting an error when I execute this script and can't figure it out.

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./upload.py", line 227, in <module>
    postImage()
  File "./upload.py", line 152, in postImage
    reddit = RedditConnection(redditUsername, redditPassword)
  File "./upload.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.modhash = r.json()['json']['data']['modhash']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 799, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 335, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python No JSON object could be decoded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128772/python-no-json-object-could-be-decoded)

Comment: I found that thread but don't see how it can help me. I have the validator open, but in my case, I don't know what to paste.

Comment: Can you just print the JSON out into the console? Also, I believe your code has information you probably shouldn't share...  imgurClientId / imgurClientSecret

Comment: I can if you can tell me how, I really don't know how I can. The machine is on CentOS 7. I can type in anything you suggest. Standing by... thank you.

Comment: as @Guy3000 mentioned, you shouldn't post your api keys.  I would probably reset your keys right away if I were you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting this exception because you are using the wrong json function here:

```
def getNumberOfFailures(path):
try:
    with open(path + '.failurecount') as f:
        return json.loads(f.read())
except:
    return 0
```

You need to do this instead:

```
def getNumberOfFailures(path):
    try:
        with open(path + '.failurecount') as f:
            return json.load(f)
    except:
        return 0
```

`json.loads()` is used on json strings. `json.load()` is used on json file objects.

As some people have mentioned, you need to reissue yourself a new API key and delete the one you posted here in your code. Other people can and will abuse those secret keys to spam Reddit under your name.

Comment: I replaced that section with your updated version and also edited the above total script so that it reflects your changes. I ran it, and have the same error. Also the API secret above is just random keystrokes.