# Converting a Perl module to JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, perl

I have a Perl (`.pm`) file that I've been trying to get into a JSON representation so that I can then search for keywords inside of it.

The directory for my script is `/Devices/bin/script.py`.  The directory where the `.pm` file lives in one level up, so `/Devices/Devices.PM`. `Devices.PM` is just a static file containing data structured as dictionaries and lists like so:

```
mylist = (
    blah => {
        other       =9,
        houses       => 1,
        etc => [
            {   etc   => '5',
                ppl      => '3,
                things       => "etc",
                animals => [ 'blah-228', 'blah-229' ]
            },
            {   etc   => '9',
                ppl      => '5',
                things       => "22",
                animals => [ 'blah-2', 'blah-5' ]
            },
        ],
        partner => 'ets',
        location => 'wherever',
    },
    blah => {
        ppl => 6,
        place => 101,
        things => 'etc',
        animals => 'whatever',
    },
```

I have:

```
os.chdir("..")
with open('Devices.pm', 'r') as f:
    json_obj = json.dumps(f)
    print json_obj
```

but I keep getting `TypeError: <open file 'SwitchConfig.pm', mode 'w' at 0x10c1f69c0> is not JSON serializable`. I have tried this several ways with no luck, including `json.dump(s)`. I keep getting different errors. Am I not understanding my `.pm` file structure correctly in order to turn it into a JSON representation?

Comment: seems related to this question [Python No JSON object could be decoded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128772/python-no-json-object-could-be-decoded), maybe try copying the file contents into something like [jsonlist.com](http://jsonlint.com)'s validator and adjust as necessary

Comment: In python 3, you need to read the file `f.read()`

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you need to read this with a Perl script (or one-liner) and so export proper JSON.

First, what is shown is not valid Perl. I'll assume typos in posting for some basic syntax errors.

There is also a missing `%` in front of `mylist`; in Perl variable names start with a sigil, `%` for hashes.  I'll assume that it is an omission in posting but that it is there. If not, you'd have to fix that.

Let me then use a file `data.pm` such as

```
%mylist = ( 
    blah => { 
        other  => 9, 
        houses => 1,
        etc    => [ { etc => '5', ppl => '3' }, { etc => '9', ppl => '5' } ]
    }
);
```

which is a short sample of posted data, with a few typos fixed.

Here is a Perl script to make JSON from it. It uses [do](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) to execute the file as a script, and thus read the data structure (hash) into the program. Then [JSON::PP](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-PP-2.27400/lib/JSON/PP.pm)
 module is used to make `JSON` out of it, since it should be installed on a system with Perl.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use JSON::PP;

my %data = do './data.pm';

my $data_json = encode_json \%data;

print $data_json, "\n";  # just to see it

my $outfile = 'data.json';
open my $fh, '>', $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile: $!";
print $fh $data_json, "\n";
close $fh;
```

The whole job is done in the first two lines.  The `JSON::PP` is a core module ([since v5.14](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.1/pod/perl5140delta.pod#New_Modules_and_Pragmata)) but if an external dependency isn't a problem use [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm), which uses the fast `JSON::XS` if installed.

This nicely fits in a one-liner

```
perl -MJSON::PP -wE'say encode_json { do "./data.pm" }' > data.json
```

where the output is redirected to the file.

Both the program and the one-liner output (broken over lines for readability)

```
{"blah":{"other":"9","houses":"1","etc":
    [{"ppl":"3","etc":"5"},{"ppl":"5","etc":"9"}]}}
```

what is the content of the file `data.json` which is written.

For this to work the `.pm` file has to contain only a valid Perl data structure.  If there is more variables than that one hash this won't work, since `do` doesn't return all that data.  Then you'd have to process the file by other means.

Comment: You need `do './data.pm'`. Without `./` it looks for `data.pm` in `@INC`, not the current directory.

Comment: @melpomene  Oh ... thank you, corrected. (I had no idea that `do` would go to `@INC`)  However, it worked exactly as posted for me (?).  (It's just better anyway.)

Comment: If you use `JSON::PP` instead of `JSON`, your code won't have any external dependencies because [`JSON::PP` has been a core module since 5.14](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5140delta#New-Modules-and-Pragmata).

Comment: It still mostly works because perl adds `.` to `@INC` by default (but that's about to go away in 5.26).

Comment: @melpomene  Thank you for `JSON::PP` note, just the right thing here.

Answer (score 0):

[`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) converts from a Python object (like `{"foo": True}`) to a string representing that object as JSON (like `'{"foo": true}'`).  You appear to be trying to go the other way and convert a file containing JSON to a Python object; the function that does this is [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load).  However, that still won't work, as `Devices.pm` does not contain JSON.  You'll need to either write a Perl script that imports `Devices.pm` and then dumps its contents as actual JSON or else write a parser for Perl in Python.  I recommend the first approach.